# Выборка тегов по содержимому

Tags: javascript

Есть 3 тега с классом `time` с текстом, к примеру:

```
<div class="time">1 hour ago,</div>
<div class="time">2 hour left,</div>
<div class="time">5 minutes from now.</div>
```

Как узнать, есть ли в этих тегах(нужно проверить каждый) слово `ago`?

Comment: что конкретно вызвало затруднения?

Comment: https://www.fl.ru/  ... всегда пожалуйста

Comment: Можно хоть какой-то код?

Comment: Перепишите вопрос так, чтобы он стал похож на вопрос, а не на техническое задание, и тогда вам помогут. Хотя... вам, наверное, и так помогут

Comment: Вопрос не сложный но требует вашей попытки

Comment: Здесь "За вас" не будут.

Comment: @Duoxx, ну это как попадется :-D

Comment: Из того, что нагуглил —придумал

`el = $(".time");`
`live = el.indexOf("ago");`

Но консоль ругается на "el.indexOf is not a function". Можете поправить меня, что не так?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s8ze6xxc/ вот

Comment: @Duoxx, ого, всё оказалось сложнее чем я думал, спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Дарова, это скорее конкретная реализация кажется сложнее. Если будешь использовать jquery То там есть [селектор `:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: `var elementsWithAgoCount = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.time')).filter((el) => el.innerHTML.indexOf('ago') > 0).length;` https://jsfiddle.net/s8ze6xxc/3/

Comment: @AGS17, почему `>0`?

Comment: @Grundy потому что быстро наклепал :) Должно быть `>=0`, согласен

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ ВСЕМ !

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elementsWithAgo = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.time')).filter((el) => el.innerHTML.indexOf('ago') >= 0);

console.log(elementsWithAgo);
console.log("Count: " + elementsWithAgo.length);
```

```html
<div class="time">1 hour ago,</div>
<div class="time">2 hour left,</div>
<div class="time">5 minutes from now.</div>
```